# jQuery: How can I fade in the navigation only after the div expands?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu button that toggles the header bar at the top of my page. How can I make all of the contents of the div (`.logo` and `.nav`) fade in/appear only after the header div has finished expanding? Otherwise you can see the nav/logo elements rearranging themselves while the `header` div expands.

A fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/L9cKt/3/

I'm thinking there is a way to delay the `display: none;` for the `.logo` and `.nav` classes until a certain time after the click event.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: You have a CSS transition which takes half a second. jQuery doesn't know about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery function on toggleClass complete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321393/jquery-function-on-toggleclass-complete)

Comment: `addEventListener("transitionend"` .. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/transitionend

Comment: @Shomz - the transition is for the menu to shrink when the user scrolls down.

Comment: @druciferre not quite unfortunately, since the content I want to fade in is part of the `tiny` class that I am toggling, not a part of a function I'd like to execute next..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't handle css transitions via jQuery you can try mimic the same behaviour using  jQuery's own `animate()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu').click(function () {
        if ($('#header').is(".tiny")) {
            $('#header').animate({
                width: "100%",
                height: "100px",
                padding: "30px"
            }, 500, function () {
                $('#header').removeClass("tiny").find("a").fadeIn();
            });


        } else {
            $('#header').addClass("tiny").find("a").hide();
            $('#header').animate({
                width: "50px",
                height: "50px",
                padding: "5px"
            }, 500);
        }

    });
});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/_wilmer/L9cKt/4/)

UPDATE: Fade in inner content,  use `contents()`

```
$('#header').removeClass("tiny").contents().fadeIn();
```

[DOCUMENTATION](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. It was a bit of an awkward problem but this is a good fix.

Comment: How can I ensure that all the content within the header fades in, not just `a` (from this line `$('#header').removeClass("tiny").find("a").fadeIn();` ) ? I think ultimately I'll change the logo to an `a` itself, but since I'm not good at jQuery, how would I tell jQuery to fade in something else as well?

Comment: another question.. I want the menu to be tiny when the user scrolls down, and currently have this in my code:

`$(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 10) {
            $('#header').removeClass('tiny');
            } else {
                $('#header').addClass('tiny');
            } 
        });`

How can I couple this with your solution?

Comment: You can reuse the function inside click move it to a different place and pass a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You should use chaining:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu').click(function () {
        $('#header a').fadeToggle("slow", function() {
          $('#header').toggleClass('tiny');
        } );
    });
});
```

(i've added a timeout for the fadein - plz see http://jsfiddle.net/f3yLg/)

Comment: As mentioned by @Shomz above - you are using a css-transition that jquery doens't know about.

Comment: @HampusBrynolf can you make the menu size change first, then fade the a?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, css transistions and animate are great, but we want to trigger js - maybe a case to stick with `.animate();`

---

One way ( more convention but not 100% accurate / *browser may not be chirpy enough to match these times up* )

After the toggleClass command we can set a timeout to match our CSS transition time.

```
$("#somediv").toggleClass("csswithtransition");
var timer = setTimeout(function() {  $("#something").hide(); },500);
/* 500 ms being the css transition time */
```

---

Another ,  we have a few events to look for, but we need all the prefixes:

- -webkitTransitionEnd
- otransitionend
- oTransitionEnd
- msTransitionEnd
- transitionend

-

```
$("#somediv").toggleClass("tiny").one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',   
  function(e) {

      $("#something").hide();

});
```

Give these a try

Comment: * use `.one()` for these rather than `.on` as `.one` is throwaway and will not hang around