# JQuery toggleClass() checkbox unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Hi Please check below code -

**HTML**

```
<div class="manage-user-freind" style="line-height:18px; cursor:pointer;">
  <span style="color:blue;">
    <img src="'+pageUrl+'/img/user-16x16.png" height="14" style="float:left; padding-top:2px;" /><input class="chk" type="checkbox" value="10" />pieter
  </span>
</div>

<div class="manage-user-freind" style="line-height:18px; cursor:pointer;">
  <span style="color:blue;">
    <img src="'+pageUrl+'/img/user-16x16.png" height="14" style="float:left; padding-top:2px;" /><input class="chk" type="checkbox" value="12" />john
  </span>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.manage-user-freind').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('clicked',function(){
            $('.chk').prop('checked', true);
     });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.clicked {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

I have used toggleClass() function. `toggleClass` is working fine but all the check-boxes clicked also not unchecked the current checkbox .

I need when I will click any div first show that div in yellow color along with current checkbox checked. Again clicking on that yellow color div will remove and also checkbox will unchecked.

Thanks.

Sorry for my English wording. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.manage-user-freind').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked').find('.chk').prop('checked', $(this).hasClass('clicked'));
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/d84z5vub/1/

Answer (score 4):

`$.toggleClass` don't have callback function. It's not async function, so you can move `$('.chk').prop('checked', true);` to next statement along toggling class:

```
$(this).toggleClass('clicked');
$('.chk').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: This doesn't toggle the state of the `checkbox`

Comment: @Tushar yes, because OP is always setting checkbox as checked, not toggling it.

Answer (score 2):

To check and uncheck, this code should work:

```
$('.manage-user-freind').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
     var checkbox = $(this).find('.chk');
     checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop("checked"));
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qff4z2v3/)

Answer (score 0):

According to this: [jquery function on toggleClass complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321393/jquery-function-on-toggleclass-complete)

you can use premise to wait until class will be changed

```
$(this).toggleClass('clicked').promise().done(function(){
    alert('a');
});
```